# github Website not getting index by search engine

Tags: html, github, web

I recently created a website to showcase my portfolio which includes little description, github link, linkedlin link and Resume. It's been a week but my website is not getting indexed by search engine.  below is meta data code.

```
<head>
    <title> Websitei</title>
    <meta name=" description"
    content=" Github Reusme Linkedin Reusme">
    <meta name = "keywords" content=" portfolio blog, Github, Linkedin, portfolio, Contact details">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="images/sample.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
```

Any suggestions to improvise head tag?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an SEO question outside [the scope defined by the SEO tag wiki page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/seo/info). It might be on-topic for [the webmasters stackexchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)